# How to find node groups with a high cohesion by relationships to intermediate nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-theory, neo4j-apoc

Minimal example:

There are some cats, who prefer to climb different types of trees.

I'd like to identify groups of cats that prefer climbing roughly the same trees.

In the example below, Lily and Bella have a 67% overlap in their preferences. They should be identified as one group.

Lune simply climbs every tree, so she should not be part of the group.

Cleo is completely disjoint from this group, i.e., has 0% overlap with Lily and Bella.

How would a query look like, that returns groups with, let's say at least 50% overlap? (In this case, one group, which is "Lily and Bella".)

```
CREATE (:Cat { name: 'Luna' });
CREATE (:Cat { name: 'Lily' });
CREATE (:Cat { name: 'Bella' });
CREATE (:Cat { name: 'Lucy' });
CREATE (:Cat { name: 'Nala' });
CREATE (:Cat { name: 'Callie' });
CREATE (:Cat { name: 'Kitty' });
CREATE (:Cat { name: 'Cleo' });

CREATE (:Tree { type: 'Red_maple' });
CREATE (:Tree { type: 'Loblolly_pine' });
CREATE (:Tree { type: 'American_sweetgum' });
CREATE (:Tree { type: 'Douglas_fir' });
CREATE (:Tree { type: 'Quaking_aspen' });
CREATE (:Tree { type: 'Sugar_maple' });
CREATE (:Tree { type: 'Balsam_fir' });
CREATE (:Tree { type: 'Flowering_dogwood' });

MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Lily' AND t.type = 'Red_maple' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Lily' AND t.type = 'Loblolly_pine' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Lily' AND t.type = 'American_sweetgum' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);

MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Bella' AND t.type = 'Red_maple' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Bella' AND t.type = 'Loblolly_pine' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Bella' AND t.type = 'Douglas_fir' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);

MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Luna' AND t.type = 'Red_maple' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Luna' AND t.type = 'Loblolly_pine' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Luna' AND t.type = 'American_sweetgum' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Luna' AND t.type = 'Douglas_fir' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Luna' AND t.type = 'Quaking_aspen' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Luna' AND t.type = 'Sugar_maple' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Luna' AND t.type = 'Balsam_fir' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Luna' AND t.type = 'Flowering_dogwood' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);

MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Cleo' AND t.type = 'Sugar_maple' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Cleo' AND t.type = 'Balsam_fir' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
MATCH (c:Cat), (t:Tree) WHERE c.name = 'Cleo' AND t.type = 'Flowering_dogwood' CREATE (c)-[:LIKES_TO_CLIMB]->(t);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? what is the result?

Comment: The problem is, I have no idea where to even start. I know how to match on single relationships, but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you really want to do is:

1. Use Node Similarity algorithm in the GDS library. The default is the Jaccard similarity, or you could also use Overlap similarity. The Node similarity algorithm will create similarity relationships between your cats. You can set the threshold by using the `similarityCutoff` parameter.
2. Once you have the similarity relationships created, you want to either run Weakly-Connected component algorithm or something like Louvain or Leiden, depending what works best for your use-case.

So in your specific use case it would look like:

## Construct projected graph

```
CALL gds.graph.project('cats', ['Cat', 'Tree'], 'LIKES_TO_CLIMB');
```

## Run node similarity algorithm with a Jaccard threshold of 0.5

```
CALL gds.nodeSimilarity.mutate('cats', {mutateRelationshipType:'SIMILAR',
    mutateProperty:'score', similarityCutoff:0.5})
```

## Run either WCC or other community detection algorithms

```
CALL gds.wcc.stream('cats', {relationshipTypes:['SIMILAR'], nodeLabels:['Cat']})
YIELD nodeId, componentId
RETURN componentId, collect(gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name) AS catGroup
```

This returns:

```
╒═════════════╤════════════════╕
│"componentId"│"catGroup"      │
╞═════════════╪════════════════╡
│0            │["Luna"]        │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│1            │["Lily","Bella"]│
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│3            │["Lucy"]        │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│4            │["Nala"]        │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│5            │["Callie"]      │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│6            │["Kitty"]       │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│7            │["Cleo"]        │
└─────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Now obviously, you can play around with `similarityCutoff` parameter and other community detection algorithms to best fit your use-case